# How copy dependencies from local gradle cache to local maven repository on Windows computer?

Tags: maven, gradle

First of all - i`m new in gradle, so sory for newbie question.

I`m have java project and build them by gradle. When gradle build , they download many dapendencies from public repository to local gradle cache.

I need copy this dependencies to local maven repository and use this repository in other maven project.
As i know gradle cache and maven repository use different format.

All job i run on Windows 10 OS.

Comment: Why not let Maven download the dependencies from the same public repository?

Comment: How can i do this, if my repository build by gradle ?
How can i use maven to download all dependencies (and save it localy)  from my project ?